# Issues with css for triangles and such

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have been asked to create an interactive logo for my client with these specifics:

- it has be responsive
- it's a logo with a clear picture at the beginning which fades in another one with the clickable items
- In this second image if I hover a specific section it has to change color to reflect the one from before

My problem is that this logo is made of triangles and I have no idea how to tackle this

Maybe I went completely wrong with my procedure

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
}

#logo_mediaofficina {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  zoom: 0.3;
}

img.puzzler_01 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeout;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeout;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation-name: fadeout;
  /* Opera */
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

img.puzzler_02 {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  animation-name: fadein;
  -moz-animation-name: fadein;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation-name: fadein;
  /* Opera */
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.categoria_homelogo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  left: 64%;
  top: 268px;
}

.categoria_homelogo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*keyframes*/

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeout {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*fadein*/

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mediaofficina_homepage">
  <!-- LOGO -->
  <div id="logo_mediaofficina">
    <img class="puzzler_01" src="http://www.mediaofficina.it/images/homepage/Home-Media-01.png" />
    <div>
      <img class="puzzler_02" src="http://www.mediaofficina.it/images/homepage/Home-Media-02.png" />
      <div class="categoria_homelogo">
        <a href="#"><img class="" src="http://www.mediaofficina.it/images/homepage/categorie_logo/Portfolio.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many way to do this but i think the best thing is using generator, it just a rectangle. u don't need any specific border radius or even specific transform in your CSS. it just a triangle right, or unshaped triangle?

Have you ever tried this in css polygon, circle, square, etc?

```
shape-outside: polygon()
```

CSS to get shape and ur words following your shape. also read this

[Shaping the Div](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/)

[Shaping div generator lvl easy](http://www.samuelrossille.com/css-shape/#1142AAy10z-37z-28z12z0)

Comment: you can see the shapes in the snippet, every section with a text is supposed to be clickable with an hover effect.

Comment: @JavisUlrick i saw them, and had u read the articles? it will help alot. if u can shape the div. u can shape the text also following with transition and rotate. within div and text u suppose to be using a tags or link

Comment: Yeah i did a quick look, didn't know polygon existed. You may have just saved my skin on this one.

Comment: ya.. :)  ps. dont asking before u search things on google. many mean person in here, u will get devote for no reason if u asking an easy question.

good luck javis

Comment: I searched but polygon never popped out that's why I didn't know it existed